# Key mapping: printable char key (like a/s/d/f) mapped to control?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap

Is it possible to use xmodmap or xkb to turn a key that usually inserts characters (like <kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>s</kbd>/<kbd>d</kbd>/<kbd>f</kbd>) into a modifier key?

I try xmodmap with what I thought would work, e.g., `add Control = a`,
but this does not lead to the desired result.

Achieving this could be useful, e.g., to turn the ISO keyboard into ASCII
by setting <kbd><</kbd> to act as <kbd>Shift</kbd>. 
But other interesting applications could be there too; e.g., having a third control.

Comment: Maybe explain the real problem you are trying to solve. If <kbd>a</kbd> is mapped to <kdb>Contrl</kdb>, how would you enter a plain <kbd>a</kbd>?

Comment: I have a laptop with ISO keyboard layout that has some keys I'm not using, and they take place of the usual shift and enter. I want to map them to their ANSI keyboard layout functions for touch typing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the `add` keyword if you wanna assign a single key to a modifier:
If I understood you correctly you can use for example `xmodmad -e "keycode YOUR_KEYCODE Control_L` or with xkb:

```
partial alhpanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "…" {
    …
    replace key <your key> {[ Control_L ]};
    …
```

Did that help?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The xkb solution works for me. Have a great day!

Comment: So please don't forget to upvote the answer and "accept" it; you'll get extra reputation credits for doing so.